# How to prove $A=\{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid x\equiv 7\pmod 8\}$ is a subset of $B=\{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid x\equiv 3 \pmod 4\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Consider the sets $A=\{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid x\equiv 7\pmod 8\}$ and $B=\{x\in\mathbb{Z} \mid x\equiv 3 \pmod 4\}$.

How to write up the proof that  $A$ is a subset of $B$?

I can see that it is true, but how to write up a proof.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include some more information what specifically you have problem with via an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

If $x \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ then we have that $x-7=8c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then we have:

$x-3=8c+4=4(2c+1)$ and then $x \equiv 3 \pmod4$.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: $\mathbb Z$ is the set of integers.

Let $x \in A$ hence $\exists m \in\mathbb Z$ such that $x-7=8m$.

$$x-3=4(2m+1) \Rightarrow x \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow x \in B.$$

Since $x$ is any arbitrary element of x, we have $A\subset B$.